# Why does the remove() Method also Removes from Copies and How to Work Around it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been experiencing a quite strange error while using python.

I have a variable named `graph`, which is a list of lists and I'm modifying and a variable `copy` which
is supposed to "remember" the original value of `graph`.

However, when I apply the remove() method to `graph`the value of copy also changes!

Here is a reproducible example:

```
graph = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,1]]
copy = graph
print("graph =" + str(graph))
print("copy =" + str(copy))
graph[0].remove(2)
print("graph =" + str(graph))
print("copy =" + str(copy))
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: `copy` **isn't** a copy. Also note you'll need a *deep* copy here, because you have a list *of lists*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating a copy, you should use copy library which creates a new object which is a copy of the old object, you have two option:

1. Shallo Copy: A shallow copy creates a new object which stores the reference of the original elements. So, a shallow copy doesn't create a copy of nested objects, instead it just copies the reference of nested objects.
2. Deep Copy: A deep copy creates a new object and recursively adds the copies of nested objects present in the original elements.

Example of Shallow Copy:

```
import copy

graph = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,1]]
copied_graph = copy.copy(graph)
```

Example of Deep Copy:

```
import copy

graph = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,1]]
copied_graph = copy.deepcopy(graph)
```

In this case, if you use **Shallow Copy** you can add another element to your `graph` list and it wont be changed in `copied_graph`, but if you change one of the lists inside the `graph` list (nested objects) it will change in `copied_graph` and if you also want to prevent this, you should use **Deep Copy**.

Comment: Can I do the same thing just without any library? My code is originally for a competitive programming problem, so I can't use any libs :(

Comment: @ArielSerranoni It's a standard library; I participated in ACM-ICPC, trust me, there's no problem using a standard library in a programming contest. In some programming languages, you can't print anything without importing/including a standard library.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I just didn't know the library you mentioned

Comment: @ArielSerranoni You're welcome, I added some extra information, please read it.